# How can I queue up custom Pyglet events while keeping input and graphics events at highest priority?

Tags: python, events, pyglet

Ok, so there's a very very long list of low priority function calls which have to be made. I would like the keyboard triggered events to continue executing right on time, and I would like the display to continue updating on time, but, when neither of these two things need to be done, I would like all remaining CPU time to be used to continue to walk down the list of low priority function calls, making them one by one.

I tried to implement this behavior by recursively calling `dispatch_event` in the last line of the event handler that handles the low priority events. This call is recursive because the type of event being dispatched is another of the same type of low priority events. The code in the body of this event handler simply pops a function call off of the long list, and executes it.

However, this doesn't work, because it turns out that `dispatch_event` actually fires the event's event handler pronto, as opposed to adding it to a queue. So, the result is that execution becomes stuck in a recursive loop, resulting in a stack overflow.

So... what should I do instead?

Comment: hi, could you post some relevant piece of code?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pyglet
from time import time, sleep

class Window(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, refreshrate):
        super(Window, self).__init__(vsync = False)
        self.frames = 0
        self.framerate = pyglet.text.Label(text='Unknown', font_name='Verdana', font_size=8, x=10, y=10, color=(255,255,255,255))
        self.last = time()
        self.alive = 1
        self.refreshrate = refreshrate

    def on_draw(self):
        self.render()

    def render(self):
        self.clear()
        if time() - self.last >= 1:
            self.framerate.text = str(self.frames)
            self.frames = 0
            self.last = time()
        else:
            self.frames += 1
        self.framerate.draw()
        self.flip()

    def on_close(self):
        self.alive = 0

    def on_key_release(self, symbol, modkey):
            print(symbol, modkey)

    def on_mouse_motion(x, y, dx, dy):
        print('Mouse from:',x,y,'moved:',dx,dy)

    def run(self):
        while self.alive:
            self.render()
            event = self.dispatch_events() # <-- This is the event queue
            sleep(1.0/self.refreshrate)

win = Window(23) # set the fps
win.run()
```

This takes care of mouse and keyborad while not clogging up any event queues. Generate events or listen to events in the event dispatcher or do the rendering you need to do in `def render()`.

Comment: It seems like this code will waste time sleeping, only executing the events up to the speed of the frame rate, but no faster. No?

Comment: @user1123936 ofc, that's what frame limiting is all about, preserving computer calculation power to other things AND to keep the frame rate stable for your machine. Users don't want to feel that the game/gui is chopping or going up and down in framerate, they want the illusion of a stable frame rate. You can remove the sleep but add your own timer in the `def render()`making it so objects only render X ammounts of time per second but the `dispatch_events()` still fire at the highest speed possible.